# I need to refactor a Angular service method and set a parameter value via another Angular service

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

The original code looked like this:

```
this.messages = <Subject<IProgressStatusObject>>wsService
     ... .connectArchivalProcessCompleteService(UrlSettings.WEBSOCKET_URL + "archiveProcessComplete")
```

...

I have to change the way the first argument is set. 
Currently it just uses a constant: 'UrlSettings.WEBSOCKET_URL' this now needs to be set from a value stored on the server. I already have a service method defined which returns the data needed but I am having difficulty setting the desired value returned from my service call.

Here is what I have so far:

```
@Injectable()
export class ArchivalProcessCompleteService {
  public messages: Subject<IProgressStatusObject>;

  constructor(
    wsService: WebsocketService,
    configurationService: ConfigurationService
  ) {
    console.log('connected with localhost url');
    this.messages = <Subject<IProgressStatusObject>>(
      wsService
        .connectArchivalProcessCompleteService(
          this.GetWebSocketUrl(configurationService) + 'archiveProcessComplete'
        )
        .map(
          (response: MessageEvent): IProgressStatusObject => {
            const data = JSON.parse(response.data);
            return {
              identifier: data.Identifier,
              isArchivingInProgress: data.IsArchivingInProgress,
              totalRecordsToArchive: data.TotalRecordsToArchive,
              numberOfRecordsArchived: data.NumberOfRecordsArchived,
              isArchivingCancelled: data.IsArchiveCancelled
            };
          }
        )
    );
  }

  GetWebSocketUrl(configurationService: ConfigurationService): string{
    let wsUrl;

    configurationService.getConfigurationData().subscribe(data => {
      const WebSocketUrl = this.doSetWebSocketUrl(data);
      wsUrl = WebSocketUrl;
    });

    return wsUrl;
  }

  private doSetWebSocketUrl(configData: Configuration): string {
    return configData.WebSocketUrl;
  }
```

I know that my doSetWebSocketUrl() method return value has the expected data set, however the return value from the GetWebSocketUrl method 'wsUrl' is always undefined?

I just need the parameter passed to my WebsocketService to look like: .connectArchivalProcessCompleteService('ws://sequoiaserver:14556/' + "archiveProcessComplete") which is the value returned from the configurationService.getConfigurationData call.

Comment: Try to reverse your calling first call `GetWebSocketUrl` and then in that service response call your messages service you will get proper response.

Comment: Thanks, once i moved the code around as suggested it pretty much sorted it.